# list dataframe to normal dataframe

Tags: r, xml, dataframe

I have two XML files that I would like to parse into dataframe in R
and then do a merge.

Getting the XML file into a listed dataframe

```
library(XML)
library(plyr)

getxmldf<-function(xmlfile){

  booksz <- xmlTreeParse(xmlfile)
  xmldf<-ldply(xmlToList(booksz), data.frame)
  xmldf.T <- t(xmldf[,2:ncol(xmldf)])
  return(xmldf.T)

}
```

then unlist it & do a merge but I got stuck in unlist & merge doesnt work...

```
df8 <- as.data.frame(lapply(df8, function(X) unname(unlist(X))))
merge(df8, df8, by = c("V5"))
str(df8, max.level = 1)
```

I attach two test XML files. They are the address dump from "Cheat Engine"

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxCrQYKS04mRV1ZEZ1Bza2Vabkk/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxCrQYKS04mRRWJUVjdqRUp3Yk0/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a look at your files, and they don't seem to have a lot of interesting information in them.

In each file there are many CheatEntry nodes which each contain 5 nodes: ID, Description, LastState, VariableType, and Address.

The ID is always sequential by 1, from 0 to 87 in the first file, 0 to 110 in the second file.

The Description is always '"No description"'.

The LastState is always empty. It does have two attributes: Value which is always 6042 in the first file, 6122 in the second, and RealAddress which is always the same as the Address node. So neither attribute has any real information to provide.

The VariableType is always "4 Bytes".

The Address has an 8 digit hex string which is always unique within and between the two files.

---

Given all of the above, I'm not sure why you want to merge them. In R, "merging" generally means *joining* rows on a key, but there's no common key between the data sets we get from these two files. Actually, perhaps ID could make sense, but given you seem to have tried "V5" in your question, this doesn't appear to be correct.

I assume you want to *combine* the two data.frames by row, which can be done with the `rbind()` function. We can process both files in one shot with `lapply()` and then use `do.call()` to invoke a single `rbind()` call on the per-file data.frames.

Also, I would recommend avoiding `xmlToList()` in favor of a targeted search for the CheatEntry nodes with `xpathApply()`, and then a call to the helper `xmlToDataFrame()` function. This will also allow us to use the `colClasses` and `stringsAsFactors` arguments of `xmlToDataFrame()` to control the data types of the resulting columns.

Putting all of this together, we have:

```
xmlFiles <- list.files(pattern='\\.CT$');
xmlFiles;
## [1] "CivilizationBE_DX11-6042.TXT.CT" "CivilizationBE_DX11-6122.TXT.CT"
res <- do.call(rbind,lapply(xmlFiles,function(xmlFile)
    xmlToDataFrame(
        xpathApply(xmlInternalTreeParse(xmlFile),'//CheatEntry'),
        c('integer','character','character','character','character'),
        stringsAsFactors=F
    )
));
head(res); tail(res);
##   ID      Description LastState VariableType  Address
## 1  0 "No description"                4 Bytes 0AEEE67C
## 2  1 "No description"                4 Bytes 0AEEE68C
## 3  2 "No description"                4 Bytes 0AF6E67C
## 4  3 "No description"                4 Bytes 0AF6E68C
## 5  4 "No description"                4 Bytes 0B827378
## 6  5 "No description"                4 Bytes 0B8992C8
##      ID      Description LastState VariableType  Address
## 194 105 "No description"                4 Bytes 25E7EAC4
## 195 106 "No description"                4 Bytes 25E7EAC8
## 196 107 "No description"                4 Bytes 25E7EAD4
## 197 108 "No description"                4 Bytes 2E15F970
## 198 109 "No description"                4 Bytes FF6A673C
## 199 110 "No description"                4 Bytes FFBCA308
```